# Correct way of determining resolution of clock_gettime on Linux

Tags: c, linux, time, profiling, clock

I'm dealing with the age-old devil of timing resolutions on Linux as part of a homework assignment. To cut a long story short, I'm trying to find the mechanism that can give me the best resolution on an Intel i5 quad-core 3.2 GHz machine running Linux version 2.6.32.

I looked up different methods, and finally am comparing performances of `clock_gettime` and `RDTSC`. I'll probably post another question for the latter, but here's what I did to find the average time required for a `clock_gettime` call:

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts_start);
for(loopindex = 0; loopindex < 1000000; loopindex++)
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts_end);
```

`ts, ts1, ts2` are of type `struct timespec`. I later calculate differences between `ts_end` and `ts_start` and divide by 1000000. This gives me 26ns.

I then thought of trying something else:

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIc, &ts1);
ts2 = ts1;
while(ts1.tv_sec == ts2.tv_sec && ts1.tv_nsec == ts2.tv_nsec)
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts2);
```

`ts1` and `ts2` are again of type `struct timespec`. I print the difference in times when the loop terminates. Now, this gives me ~100ns.

I'm confused as to what the right approach is here, and what is the right value. Is there some fundamental point I'm missing in how the times should be interpreted? Also, this got me confused about the term "resolution". Does 26ns/100ns indicate that the actual resolution of `clock_gettime` on the system is 26ns/100ns?

**Edit**

I also varied the loop count of the first method and used smaller numbers. The first call takes a long time (~140ns), the second lesser and so on until it evens out at 26ns for all subsequent calls. I'm guessing this is due to caching. Does this affect the correct value?

Comment: Taking the average is definitely misleading. When you read the same value twice, the difference is zero, and that lowers the average. So I'd say that 100nsec is the more correct of the two values. I typically run the second loop thousands of times, keeping a histogram of the differences. The expectation is that every difference will be a multiple of the resolution.

Comment: @user3386109: Oops, I made a mistake - the first method was different. Please check the question again.

Comment: The first method is measuring the amount of time it takes to call the `clock_gettime` function. That's an important piece of information, because it's possible that the time-to-call-the-function is greater than the clock resolution. In that case, it's more difficult to determine the clock resolution. However, that loop tells you nothing about the resolution of the clock. It only tells you that calling `clock_gettime` takes about 26nsec.

Comment: @user3386109: Even more confused now :/. In the second method, the second call to the function would NOT terminate the loop if it took less than 1ns to complete, but we know it does take more. So it should terminate the loop on the second call thus giving the time required to call the function and hence should be same as first method. Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: The second method keeps calling `clock_gettime` until the time changes. So if the clock resolution is 100nsec, and the time-to-call-the-function is 26nsec, then you will typically call `clock_gettime` 4 times before the loop breaks. You can confirm that by putting a counter in the loop.

Comment: @user3386109: Odd, the counter reports 2.

Comment: Yeah, well updating the counter takes time too.

Comment: @user3386109: Alright, so what would be the right thing to do here to find the resolution? I've added another edit to the question.

Comment: We've exceeded our quota of comments. I suggest consulting with one of your classmates, or a teacher's assistant.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question, but what about using `clock_getres()`?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to know the resolution of the internal clock is to use the function `clock_getres(2)`, as specified in posix.

```
int clock_getres(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *res);
```